# Git - ignore directory when pulling, don't when pushing

Tags: git, gitignore, git-push, git-pull

I searched for an answer to this, but I just found other stuff related to `.gitignore`.

I have a `demo` folder in my repo for a demonstration of my package. When I push, I want it to be uploaded just because I want it stored and updated along with the package.

However, when someone clones the repo, I don't want them to have the `demo`, because they don't need it. They only need the files in `lib` to use the package.

### What I tried

I tried adding `demo` to my `.gitignore`, `git add . -f` and then pushing. The `demo` was uploaded. However, when I `git clone` the repo in another folder, the demo files are still downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Either `demo` is part of the repo or not. `.gitignore` is only effective on **untracked** files. As soon as a file is tracked, `.gitignore` is not taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

git commit what them (don't push), then git pull:

1. git status to check what you have done.
2. remove from list which files you will accept change after git pull
3. then `git add -A` to makesure they're will not changed
4. then `git commit -m "your message"`, after that don't push
5. finally `git pull`